# Scaling in gideros

Tags: lua, gideros

```
local scaling = Application.CENTER
application:setScaleMode(scaling)
```

I tried using above code in Gideros but it gives an error that 'bad argument #1 to 'setScaleMode' (string expected, got nil) at setScaleMode, how can I fix this ?Actually, It did not recognise Application.CENTER , though according to Apress Lua game development, It should.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Application:setScaleMode`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the constants are not set (probably a bug), but you can still use the values from here:
[http://docs.giderosmobile.com/reference/gideros/Application/setScaleMode#Application:setScaleMode](http://docs.giderosmobile.com/reference/gideros/Application/setScaleMode#Application%3asetScaleMode)

As `application:setScaleMode("center")`

But you can also set the value in the Gideros Studio project properties

Comment: @ArtursSosins: If it was that way, then I should not be able to set orientation either, but I was.

Comment: Why not, if you look at the list of properties under Application class you will see in the docs, there are orientation constants, but there are no scaling constants, as docs are generated directly from the code, it means there are also no scaling constants in the code, but there are orientation constants

http://docs.giderosmobile.com/reference/gideros/Application#Application